# D3.js + webgl (2D) Please suggest

Tags: webgl

Hey guys this is the what I am working on.
 http://bioverto.org

If you choose any
Upload from a database ->mint full network->choose any graph.
then you can view a graph.

I am currently using d3.js for the graphs.
It works well for node length less than 1000.as size increases its performance decreases.
But now I need to deploy graphs on size more than 1000 nodes and edges.

To boost performance I was thinking of using webgl 2D.

Can you please suggest how should I proceed.

I am new to web GL.

Thank you in advanced.